# How do I link two sets of y value data that have common x values

Tags: python, arrays, csv

Trying to link two sets of data that have common observation numbers. One data array only has a subset of the observation numbers in the other array so some of the data in the second array needs to be ignored.

Tried a double for loop but don't really know how to program it properly

```
array1=[[19909,20111,30234],[543,643,743]]
array2=[[23456,98765,19909,20111,30234],[56789,6789,876,542,111]]
```

Expected result is for 'y values' in array1 to link with corresponding 'y values' in array2. For example, for observation number 19909 with y value 543, array would be produced with [[543], [876]] as 19909 is of same index as 876 y value in array2

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using arrays, this really looks like a case for `dict`. So,

```
dict1 = {array1[0][i]: array1[1][i] for i in range(len(array1[0]))}
dict2 = {array2[0][i]: array2[1][i] for i in range(len(array2[0]))}
```

And then, you can use `dict2.get(19909)` or

```
[dict2.get(item) for item in dict1.keys()]
```

Else, if you are stuck with using arrays, you have:

```
array2[1][array2[0].index(19909)]
```

Keep in mind to put this last line within a `try except ValueError` block for items present in array1 but not in array2.

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays

Comment: Lists...yes. Python lists.